# Normal string className in CSS module

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-modules

Is there any way to write normal type className on React using css module. Like I want to write className="Foo Bar" avoiding className{ ${foo} ${bar} of CSS Module.

Comment: `className="Foo Bar"`, you can access this element with class `Foo` or `Bar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`className="Foo Bar"` When you inspect the element then you can notice, the element has assigned the class **Foo** and **Bar**.

The way CSS module works, if you are assigning class `Foo` on any element, then you can inspect it has been assigned class like, `Foo_asd113d3__random_string`.

That's why `className="Foo Bar"` will not work in CSS module

Answer (score 0):

Could it be maybe agglomerate in one, like:

```
const myClass = `${foo} ${bar}`;
```

and

```
<div className={myClass} />
```

a solution?

On the other hand, if you're using style component, you should call those class like

```
const myClassStyle = styled.css`${foo} ${bar}`;
const myComponent = styled.div`${myClassStyle}`;
```

to make it works